# Import data into MATLAB from SQL database: 2 mil rows takes 30 sec, but 6 mil takes 21 min?

Tags: matlab, postgresql

**I can import 2 million rows using Matlab's DB toolbox in about 36 seconds. How can I import 6 million rows in under twenty minutes?**

The final fetch step of the query below takes about 36 seconds.

```
q = 'select ... from mytable limit 2000000'; %notice 2 mil limit
result = exec(conn, q);
final_result = fetch(result);  % Takes about 36 seconds.
```

My overall table has 6,097,227 rows. **But if I do:**

```
q = 'select ... from mytable';
result = exec(conn, q);
final_result = fetch(result);
```

MATLAB *entirely loses it* on the final fetch step! CPU usage goes to about 500-600% (i.e. 6/8 cores are being used), and it takes forever. Currently, with it set to fetch in 10k batches, it eventually finished in just over 21 minutes.

**Ideas? What to do?** I really struggling to see how how this isn't at least roughly linear in the number of rows. Have I crossed some weird limit?

BTW: whole query and import into R takes about 43 seconds in R using PostgreSQL driver etc... and 0 fiddling around. I can import in Stata in a similar time using ODBC.

Note: in the above queries `...` are 10 or so numeric variables: some integers, some double precision. None are text.

Comment: Can you use Node.js to do the import?

Comment: @vitaly-t I don't really see how Node.js applies here? (I edited the question a bit, I may have been unclear.)

Comment: In that case I can only advise in general, as I did in my answer below.

Comment: Do you fit in memory with the larger data set? Unreasonable slowing-down is often due to thrashing.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Final table is .48GB and I have 16GB of memory. Raw table size can't be the issue. But maybe something weird happening with thrashing at the Java heap layer? hmmm... I have the max heap size set for 4GB though. I find it all rather bizarre. Maybe a question for Matlab support or just not using MATLAB for this analysis...

Comment: @MatthewGunn I see. Have you tried something silly such as setting `limit` that lets your entire table fit? If the behaviour is odd, maybe the solution is odd too:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone encounters this type of problem in the future, I've found for *giant* 1GB sized queries, it's faster and more robust to:

1. Use COPY or similar to write the query results to a csv file.
2. Read the csv file into Matlab (eg. with readtable).

Answer (score 1):

This is to advise on the general strategy for large imports like this. And if any of the components that you use fail to follow it, then you will have problems, naturally.

First, import your records in batches of between 1,000 and 10,000 records, depending on the average size of your records.

Second, insert each batch with a single multi-row `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(columns...) VALUES (first-insert values), (second-insert values),...
```

i.e. concatenate your all your records of each batch into a single multi-row insert and execute it that way. It will provide a tremendous saving on the IO.